# Windows xp remote shutdown

Tags: windows, registry, windows-xp, shutdown

I m a computer teacher in computer lab. I have approxly 30 pc in lab.

I want to enable remote shutdown in all pc.

I have all pc's admin rights. There are no domain in lab.

So I write all pc ip's in one text file.

I used "shutdown -i" command and copy all the ip's and paste it to windows.

But some pc not showdown and some properly shoutdown.

There are access denied error display for some pc shutdown.

My question is I want to make one universal .reg file, that I want to run in every pc and enable remote shutdown in every pc.

Every pc run Windows xp sp3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no registry settings that you can tweak in order to enable remote shutdown.

You just need to provide the correct set of login credentials with the command. But as there is no possibility to send a username and password with this command, you have to do a little trick:
 Connect a network share from the remote computer using an user account from the remote PC (also IPC$ works). By doing so, you have authenticated to this PC for further operations. After that, you can send the shutdown command.
I am using it successfully in the exactly same way as described here in a C# program.

Comment: this thing do by the psexec windows file and make all pc admin password as same and all pc taken in domain. so as per domain administrator i do the the command to all pc as admin.